# powershell code to find files in subfolders

Tags: powershell

I have a folder called RiverData, the folder has around 5000 sub folders. each sub folder has .tif image files. for example there is folder called 5454354 which have file SCN-12343.tif, I want a powershell code that can create a out file with name of folder and name of files in a subfolder the code I am using is

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName | Out-file C:\river.txt
```

now the trouble doing this way is some folders which have subfolders like scn-0121213.tif and inside that subfolder there are several .tif files

this code is not fetching those files.

Comment: Because you're telling `Get-ChildItem` to only find directories by using `?{ $_.PSIsContainer }`, so it will never return any files

Comment: thanks looks like after removing it worked